# How to use google storage in PHP

Tags: php, storage

Is there anyone who has a working example for Google Storage in PHP? I have have found several projects for this, but none of them seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Google Storage exposes a RESTful API and some pretty fantastic documentation:

- http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/developer-guide.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/hellogooglestorage.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/developer-guide.html#overview

It's all there for you to review and implement.

Comment: Yes, i've read them all, and all of it need an Authorization parameter, which is came from oauth 2. From what i've read, oauth 2 is ALWAYS need user confirmation of the service, and what i'm trying to do is get my file from GS and use it in my css, it's very troublesome if my users should confirm that.

Comment: So, authorize yourself, and use that in the backend with cURL as a parameter your users don't see and store everything as You....

Comment: well, i'm looking for more convenient way, if it is the only way, then... this night will become a long coding night